# Changing variables according to time checked or time ran

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
import time

url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price'
r = requests.get(url).json()
while True:
    for x in r['stockList']:
        if x['symbol'] == 'MSFT':
            msft_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'AAPL':
            aapl_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'AMZN':
            amzn_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'PYPL':
            pypl_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'GOOGL':
            googl_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'TSLA':
            tsla_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'FB':
            fb_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'DIS':
            dis_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'TD':
            td_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'NVDA':
            nvda_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'V':
            v_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'NFLX':
            nflx_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'WMT':
            wmt_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'ADBE':
            adbe_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'CM':
            cm_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'NKE':
            nke_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'DELL':
            dell_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'TWTR':
            twtr_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'NSU':
            nsu_price = (x['price'])
        elif x['symbol'] == 'KO':
            ko_price = (x['price'])
        time.sleep(3600)
```

So this is the code I have so far for some stocks which I want to analyze in more detail. I have the stock prices which I get whenever the data in the API is updated but what I want to do is store the price of a stock at like the beginning of the day when the market opens and also at the end of the day. Which is why I have import time and the time.sleep(3600) which I think checks every hour. How can I store the price of the stock at the start of the day and the end of the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question but here’s a stab at a solution. What you can do is create a dictionary that stores data (you can also probably create a class which is representative of your data but a dictionary is probably simpler for a quick example). You then can create a dictionary (below it’s stored_results) which has your stocks that you want to keep track of. Then you can get the current time and write some comparison to what would be the start and the end time (I set it so it recognizes anytime as such below). You can then update keys in the dictionary to see what the start and the end value should be. You can also write out the stored_results dictionary out to a file if you want using `json.dump()` Hopefully this helps.

```
import requests
import datetime

url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price'
r = requests.get(url).json()

# Where you want to store results
stored_results = { 
    'NFLX': {}, 
    'MSFT': {}, 
}

# Functions that check whether it’s a start or an end time
def is_start_time(current_time):
    return True
def is_end_time(current_time):
    return True

# You would probably need to put the below code in your while loop
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
for stock in r['stockList']:
    symbol = stock['symbol']
    price = stock['price']
    if symbol in stored_results:
        if is_start_time(current_time):
            stored_results[symbol]['start_time'] = price
        if is_end_time(current_time):
            stored_results[symbol]['end_time'] = price
print('stored_results', stored_results)
```

Comment: alright this seems to make sense to me but I have just one question. For the start_time and end_time I should make it so that whatever time the stock market is open. I set the start_time to that and the end_time vice versa. So that when I check the price of the stock and the current time matches the start_time or end_time, I can store it in lets say two seperate dicts one for the starting price of the stock when the market opens, and one for when it closes. And then with those two dicts I can manipulate certain data like percentage of increase or decrease and etc etc.

Comment: yup that works. I think the above example, I’m storing the start_time and end_time as fields inside of the same dictionary but you can split them into two different ones as well. it’s more of a matter of preference.